# script host not processing script command line parameters

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Given a vbscript file, I have 3 ways to run it from a command line:

```
c:> cscript test.vbs
c:> wscript test.vbs
c:> test.vbs
```

WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count & WScript.Arguments.Named.Count (the number of parameters passed to the script) are always correct when I specify which script engine to use (the first 2), but are always 0 when I don't (the last one).

The ultimate goal is to have 1 script run a 2nd script with parameters, but since I'm not specifying the script engine (and don't want to) it means the 2nd script never receives the parameters the 1st script sends it.

(I don't want to specify the script host since doing that forces me to also specify a path to the script, and this is ultimately going to be used by different people who can't be trusted to always put the scripts in the same place on every machine. So I just want to be able to run the script and have the OS pick the executable based on the file extension)

My default script host is set to cscript, but when using the last method to run the script Wscript.FullName reports wscript.exe, which I just don't understand at all... ?

[EDIT] 
Updated to add clarification on the issue regarding running a script without specifying the full path. This doesn't work for me, and I'm not sure I expect it to?

```
c:\test> type test.vbs
wscript.echo wscript.fullname

c:\test>cd\

c:\>set path=c:\test;%path%

c:\>cscript.exe test.vbs
Input Error: Can not find script file "test.vbs"
```

Comment: *"I don't want to specify the script host since doing that forces me to also specify a path to the script"* - Ermm.. no it doesn't. Your first two examples prove that. You need to show a [mcve] as it stands I can't follow your logic as the examples you've posted will all work, path or no path.

Comment: In the first 2 examples I'm running cscript.exe from the folder where the .vbs file is.   If it's in a different folder, even a folder in the path, cscript.exe returns an error.    If I could figure out StackOverflow's screwy formatting rules I'd post a better explanation.